# Discrepancy between grid and document crosshair

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids

I noticed this discrepancy while editing a pattern `0,8` x `1,6` mm I have tried setting horizontal grid to `50%` and to `0,8` mm and the result is the same. If I use ruler tool grid lines are distant `0,8` mm from the middle one. However document crosshair gives a different indication for the center.

While I drag the selection tool, it also show to be at `0,8` mm while above the purple crosshair and not the guide. What one should I listen to?

[image]

Comment: Think about the following thing: Do you have a odd or even number of pixels? Photoshop is not illustrator everything happens on pixels.

Comment: @joojaa that was right, it was 9 pixel, so I made a 8 pixel pattern and was able to split, thank you!

Comment: You should write an self answer of this.

Comment: @joojaa well you should really, it was your clue to address me into the right way